# Websphere maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, websphere, websphere-8

I want to create bean which will integrate with WOLA (integration with COBOL).

In order to do so I need annotate bean by `@RemoteHome(com.ibm.websphere.ola.ExecuteHome.class)`. However this is IBM artifact which should reside in ola_apis.jar.

Do you know how can I resolve this dependency? How to add it to pom? I'm searching for some IBM repository but cannot find any.

My understanding is that for creating EAR for Websphere I should be able to create simple maven project in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM provides the APIs required for the Liberty profile in an IBM hosted maven repository. The maven repository is [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/). Once your maven can find this repository for the WOLA API you would want to use the following in your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.zosLocalAdapters</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Technically these are the Liberty profile APIs, but in this case they APIs are common between liberty profile and full profile so there shouldn't be a problem using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either include the dependency as system scope in your POM (however, this is not recommended), or you take the JAR file and upload it in a custom Maven repository within your company (or at least install it in your local repository). You can choose the group and artifact id as you want, when you do that.

Since those JARs are part of WebSphere, which has a proprietary license, there is no public Maven repository, where you could download it.